# Error during Export notes document to Ms Excel with xlsx.format.

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

Currently i need to modify my code from old version microsoft excel extension to newer version. which is from .xls to xlsx. I not sure why it give an "file not found" error.

below is part of lotus script agent of creating excel sheet.

```
    Dim xl, xlwbk, xlsht, template$, ori$
    Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
'   ori = "C:\Cargo Reports\importINV - GST.xls"
    ori = "C:\Cargo Reports\importINV - GST.xlsx"
'   template = path + "importINV - GST (" + Format$(Now, "d.m.yyyy-h.nn.ssAM/PM") +").xls"
    template = path + "importINV - GST (" + Format$(Now, "d.m.yyyy-h.nn.ssAM/PM") +").xlsx"
    FileCopy ori, template
    Set xlwbk = xl.Workbooks.open(template)
    Set xlsht = xlwbk.ActiveSheet   

    xlsht.columns("A:T").entirecolumn.autofit

    xl.visible = True 
    Print "Export Invoice - GST complete!"
```

[image: File not found]

if change back to xls will be created succesfully.

Can anyone point me the correct way of creating newer version excel file extension?

Comment: Please add a minimal error handling to your code. First line: `On error goto ErrorHandler` and then at the end of the Sub: `Exit Sub<NewLine>ErrorHandler:<NewLine>Msgbox Err & "," & Error & " in line " & erl` Then we see, in which line the error occurs...

Comment: Is the document that you copy `C:\Cargo Reports\importINV - GST.xlsx` really there?

Comment: found the error already.  i forgot to amend my "template" to xlsx...  that y cant find the document~